# Expected Discounts and Price reductions during Thanksgiving - Christmas?

Tags: canon-550d, equipment-recommendation, pricing

I know that this is a bit time-bound and subjective question, but this forum is probably the best place to ask.

I want to buy a Canon T2I (Rebel 550D0), which is currently USD 899 (incl 18-55 Lens). With an instant rebate of USD 50, it comes to USD 850. Convert that to Indian Rupees, and it becomes an even larger sum (for me ;) )

Would like to know, given the recent announcement of 60D etc, and the holiday season, approximately how much the 550D would be available for around Thanksgiving season.

If there are huge (15-20+ %) discounts then I can hold off making a purchase here and get the camera from US.

If there are significant price reductions in street price, then also I can hold off making a purchase here, and either get it from US or wait for the reduction to percolate to the market here, and purchase locally (provides warranty)

If the discounts are not that significant, will buy here (at least the warranty part will be covered on a local purchase).

Also, How are prices in the US compared to Singapore ? Singapore is an attractive place for us Indians to get equipment from, given its proximity.

Thanks !

Comment: @Rob : More than 90% of the questions regarding photography are subjective :)

Comment: I'm guessing that the downvotes are because the question is about future expectations, which can not be known.  This has not yet been deemed off-topic, but some similar types of questions have been: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130/should-we-allow-questions-about-unreleased-cameras

Comment: One of the Canon forums would be a better place to ask this question. You will get many more replies and a spirited debate as a bonus.

Comment: Actually this question is no different than a few others on photo.se (for example, "should I upgrade from EOSxx to EOSx or wait) etc. But I get it. Perception about the question matters :)

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3770/21

Comment: I think "what are the prices for this specific equipment this particular season going to be" is way out of scope. But "does camera equipment pricing generally drop during the US holiday shopping season" seems quite reasonable.

Comment: @Abhinav — FWIW, that EOSxx question is also problematic and in fact no longer with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cyber Monday (Monday after Thanksgiving) this year is on November 29th.  Generally all the major online stores have huge sales.  Black Friday, the Day after Thanksgiving (November 26) is a good time to go shopping at Brick and Mortar stores.  As for the percentages, Rob has it correct, can't predict the percentages off.

Comment: This is true for the US, but there are no guarantees that other parts of the world would care about US holidays.

Comment: Understood - but mentioning Thanksgiving led me to believe the question was north american centric.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I was looking for US (and Singapore) prices.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why all the down votes. Maybe just wrong place to ask. There of course are sales in the US around this time. As to how big, ask the retailers.